# HTML twitter widget fails

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, widget

Recently the twitter widget on my webpage fails to load. 
Any ideas, I just can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Line 224 at https://github.com/bicyclize/bicyclize.github.io/blob/master/index.html

the widget is from twitter  https://publish.twitter.com/# :

Tweets by bicyclize

Thanks

Comment: well, its not working on my browser. yours? http://bicyclize.com/

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your browser. Works fine in firefox developer

Comment: strange, explorer works, firefox not. Jaromanda, if you answer I'll credit you with the response. thanks a lot